# WSO2 DB Lookup Mediator does not check empty values in WSO2 EI 6.3.0

Tags: wso2, lookup, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am using wso2 lookup mediator for checking record already exist in db or not based on some input parameter. if i pass empty value for "EGC" it doesn't return id even though record available in DB.

**Request**:

```
{
    "Stockno":"HS19293",
    "EGC":""
}
```

**Code**:

```
<property expression="json-eval($.Stockno)" name="Stockno" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property expression="json-eval($.EGC)" name="EGC" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
       <dblookup description="Lookup CarSalesStock">
            <connection>
                <pool>
                    <dsName>jdbc/QRSagASGDataSource</dsName>
                </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
            <sql><![CDATA[select id from devVB.CarSales_Stock where StockNumber=? and EGC=?]]></sql>
                        <parameter expression="get-property('Stockno')" type="VARCHAR"/>
                        <parameter expression="get-property('EGC')" type="VARCHAR"/>
                        <result column="1" name="ID"/>
            </statement>
        </dblookup>
         <log level="custom">
        <property name="retrieved ID" expression="get-property('ID')"/>
        </log>
```

Database:

[image: CarSales_Stock table]

Comment: Try to execute the same SQL query (select id from devVB.CarSales_Stock where StockNumber='HS19293' and EGC='') directly to the database and check if you can retrieve the data. It seems that an empty string is passed to the SQL query instead of a a null value.

Comment: Hi @ShanakaPremarathna,
if i execute the same query in workbench, it will not return id even pass "NULL" as value for "EGC". shall i know how to skip NULL or empty values during query execution??